# creating ROC curve with Sensitivity and 1- specificity in R

Tags: r, roc

I have successfully created 2x2 contingency table.The contingency table is created through the following process:

```
plus <- ua.mask + vm.c.m.s;
minus <-ua.mask - vm.c.m.s;
```

Here, ua.mask and vm.c.m.s are raster layers(can be considered as matrix) where the cells are given the values 0 (for non urban areas) and 1(for urban).ua.mask is the reference map and vm.c.m.s is a map which accuracy is what I want to check.

```
 m <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=2)

m[1,1] <- length(which(plus[]==2))
m[1,2] <- length(which(minus[]==-1))
m[2,1] <- length(which(minus[]==1))
m[2,2] <- length(which(plus[]==0))
```

So, when I add and subtract these raster layers the cells will have the values of 1,-1,0 and 2. That means, i will have 4 possible outcomes where 2 =TP, -1 = FP, 1=TP, 0 =TN.
At, the end I get a 2x2 contingency table which looks like this:

```
          [,1]      [,2]
    [1,]  2           -1
    [2,]  1           0
```

Then, I calculated Sensitivity (TPR) and 1-Specificity(FPR).

Now, I would like to plot all pairs of sensitivity and 1-specificity to create an ROC curve (sensitivity vs. 1-specificity) for all the cities, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I went through ROCR package in R but couldn't understand how the function (prediction and perform) works in my case.

Or, are my input datas even correct for ROC-Curves?

Any help that you can provide would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question because your example isn't fully reproducible. Specifically, we don't know what `ua.mask` and `vm.c.m.s` are or even what their structure is. Can you please include them, or at least provide some toy data with the same structure?

Comment: Hi @ulfelder , i have updated the question. i hope it is sufficient. Thank you! :)

Comment: Check out also the ROC function from the Epi package http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=Epi/man/ROC.Rd&d=R_CC

Comment: I still don't understand the structure of your data well enough to provide a confident answer, but I suspect that a ROC curve isn't appropriate for what you're doing. ROC curves are for comparing predicted probabilities from a binary classifier to observed classes, not for summarizing confusion matrices in general.

Comment: Usually for binary classifiers we have four outcomes ,right? so the 2x2 contingency table i have above are the four outcomes that i get where 2 =TP, -1 = FP, 1= FN and 0 =TN. From this table, i then calculated FPRs and TPRs. and now i want to plot ROC curve using these datas but when I go through ROC CURVE papers, I come across terms like threshold n cut-off values which I do not have. so, is it possible to plot an roc curve just from contingency table? @ulfelder

Comment: ROC curves are for situations where you have a binary observed classification but a continuous prediction, almost always a probability of membership in one of the two classes. They cannot be computed when the prediction is also binary. For those situations, you might check out the `verify()` or `table.stats()` functions in the 'verification' package.

Comment: @ulfelder Hi, thanks! I'll have a look at it. :)